# Undefined behavior when using cout to do calculations

Tags: string, cout

I have an empty string

```
string A="";
cout<<A.size()-1;
```

It prints 2^32-1 that is `4294967295`

But expected answer is obvious `-1`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to subtract 1 from the size of an empty string? How do you plan to use the result?

Comment: I was solving a ques which required to check one less than the given string size and string could also be empty . My code broke their and I couldn't find why

Answer (score 0):

You can get the expected output by casting it to int

```
cout << int(A.size()-1);
```

string::size() returns size_t which is usually defined as unsigned int.
That is why it is printed like that.
By casting it to int, we can have it interpreted as a signed int.

Answer (score 0):

string::size returns size_t which is an unsigned integral type (the same as member type string::size_type). So the answer is correct. What you want is a signed integral:

```
cout << static_cast<int>(A.size())-1;
```

here casting is safe because obviously size is less than INT_MAX.